# Incorrect Promise return value

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to make a function returns whether an id is the validId.
However, it turns out that sometimes, even if `await isValidId(230)` is `true`, `validId` is not 230.

I assume this is because promises are always resolved asynchronously. Is that right? How am I supposed to design this function then?

```
let validId = 230;
let isValidId = function(id){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    //async code
    resolve(validId === id);
  });
}

if (await isValidId(230)){
  //validId is not necessary 230
}
```

Here's a more complete example.

```
let playerAskedToLogOut = false;
let playersOnline = ['MyUsername'];
let canPlayerUseItem = async function(player,itemId){      
  let hasItem = await Database.playerHasItem(player, itemId);
  let isStillOnline = playersOnline.includes(player);
  playerAskedToLogOut = true;  //normally called by another function
  return hasItem && isStillOnline;    
};

setInterval(() => {
  useItems();
  logOutPlayers();
}, 100);

let useItems = async function(){      
  if (await canPlayerUseItem('MyUsername', 'hammer')){
    //the player is not online anymore. Yet, await canPlayerUseItem returned true
  }
}
let logOutPlayers = function(){
  if(playerAskedToLogOut)
    playersOnline = []
}
```

Comment: Why is `isValidId` asynchronous?

Comment: Separately: What is it *really* meant to do?

Comment: I think you will have to show us your real code including the async code because the problem is likely not in what you show here.

Comment: Ok. I'll write a more detailed example.

Comment: I second that notion. You have simplified your example so much that it doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: What is `// async code`?

Comment: [Avoid the `new Promise` constructor with an `async function` executor!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)

Comment: `// the player is definetly still online. The error is somewhere else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The code in the question has a syntax error: It's using `await` in a non-`async` function, which doesn't work.</s> *(You've edited the code again to make `canPlayerUseItem` `async`)*

First: There's no purpose at all in using `new Promise` within an `async` function. The function creates a promise for you automatically. So that code (as of this writing, you keep changing it) really should be just:

```
let canPlayerUseItem = async function(player,itemId){
  let hasItem = await Database.playerHasItem(player, itemId);
  let isStillOnline = playersOnline.includes(player);
  return hasItem && isStillOnline;
};
```

The only reason `canPlayerUseItem`'s promise would resolve with `true` would be if `hasItem` comes back truthy and `playersOnline` contains `player` as of when we do that check, which is **after** we've waited for `playerHasItem`.. If the player is not online when you call `canPlayerUserItem` but *is* online when the `playerHasItem` check has completed, it will resolve with `true`.

If you want to do the `playersOnline` check *before* waiting for the `playerHasItem` call:

```
let canPlayerUseItem = async function(player,itemId){
  if (playersOnline.includes(player)) {
    return false;
  }
  return await Database.playerHasItem(player, itemId);
};
```

Or if you want to check **both** (but they could have gone offline, then come back online, in-between):

```
let canPlayerUseItem = async function(player,itemId){
  if (playersOnline.includes(player)) {
    return false;
  }
  let hasItem = await Database.playerHasItem(player, itemId);
  let isStillOnline = playersOnline.includes(player);
  return hasItem && isStillOnline;
};
```

---

With your latest edit, you've suggested that something is removing the player from the online array **after** the promise resolution. That suggests to me that you're asking about how you can know the player is still online in the code *using* `canPlayerUseItem`.

Answer: You can't. **Nothing** you do in `canPlayerUseItem` can protect you from the race condition inherent in this:

```
if (await canPlayerUseItem(player, itemId)) {
    // They player may now be offline
}
```

...because it's possible for the player to sign out after `canPlayerUseItem` has done its check but before your code consuming that result runs. This is the nature of asynchronous code. The above is basically this:

1. `flag = canPlayerUseItem(player, itemId)`
2. Yield until end of this event loop iteration
3. `if (flag) ...` (at which point the player may no longer be logged in)

If you need to do that check, you'll have to do it yourself *outside* the asynchronous function:

```
if (await Database.playerHasItem(player, itemId) && playersOnline.includes(player)) {
    // As of this event loop, the player is online, and had the item
    // when we checked a moment ago
}
```

which is:

1. `flag = Database.playerHasItem(player, itemId)`
2. Yield until the end of this event loop iteration
3. `if (flag && playersOnline.includes(player)`...

Comment: @RainingChain - The update to the question doesn't really change the answer: It will resolve with `true` if `hasItem` is truthy and the player is still online (e.g., still in the `playersOnline` array) as of when the promise *resolves*. Which seems like what you'd want.

Comment: The player is online when `resolve` is called but not necessarily within the `if (await canPlayerUseItem(...){ ... }`

Comment: @RainingChain: Well, which do you want to check? As I said in the answer, if you want to check *before* it resolves (for instance, when you first call it), check then and remember the result.

Comment: @RainingChain: I've updated the answer to address what I think is your real question.